# UIImageView is not covering correct cell in UITableView when cell is selected in iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am working on an app where I have a UITableView that has a selection bar that is supposed to highlight the selected cell.  The selection bar is animated, and is supposed to move to whichever cell is selected inside the table.  Unfortunately, the image that I have is not highlighting the correct cell.  Rather, it is highlighting the cell that is two rows above it.  I am not sure why that is.  I have added the UITableView, and the UIImageView to the main view in Interface Builder.  Here is my relevant code below:

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    [UIView animateWithDuration:.3 animations:^{
        CGRect rect = [tableView rectForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        _imageView.frame = rect;
    }];

}
```

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong, and what I need to do to correct this?

Thanks in advance to all who reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it may be because of not getting the desired rect from the method. Your rect is showing the frame rectangle in tableView's coordinate system. Try changing the rect from table view's coordinate system to the root view's coordinate system in which the _imageView is a subview of.

```
CGRect rect = [self.view convertRect:[tableView rectForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] fromView:tableView];
```